# Leaflet map preventing browser scroll

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

Whenever the mouse pointer is hovering over a leaflet map, the browser does not scroll up or down. This happens even when I affix minZoom and maxZoom to an equal value. Is there a solution to this?

```
php.poverty.map.2009 <-
leaflet(options = leafletOptions(minZoom = 12, maxZoom = 12)) %>%
addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
addPolygons(data = php.df.polygon.2009, 
          fillColor = ~php.pal.2009(percent), 
          color = "#b2aeae", # must use hex colors
          fillOpacity = 0.7, 
          weight = 0.3, 
          smoothFactor = 0.2,
          popup = php.popup.2009) %>%
addLegend(pal = php.pal.2009, 
        values = php.df.polygon.2009$percent, 
        position = "bottomright", 
        title = "Percent of Households <br> Living below Poverty <br> (Census, 2009)",
        labFormat = labelFormat(suffix = "%"))
php.poverty.map.2009
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my second attempt at answering this question I came across the [`leaflet.extras`](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras) package which implements a selection of leaflet plugins in R. One of these is the [`Leaflet.Sleep`](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.Sleep) plugin which can be implemented by adding the `suspendScroll()` function to your leaflet map in R.

#### Basic Example

First, install `leaflet.extras` using `devtools::install_github('bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras')`.

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
    suspendScroll()
```

See [this page](http://rpubs.com/bhaskarvk/suspended-scroll) for an example.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask two more questions? (1) On a smartphone, swiping over the map prevents scroll. However, the phone's browser still does not scroll down. Is there a workaround this? (2) Is there a function that I can apply latency on leaflet response to hovering? I am making this is for my [blog](http://americanpolicy.me/SNAP_Arlington.html)

Comment: The suspendScroll() no longer works and the author has abandoned the project unfortunately and recommends people not to use it as the javascript is outdated and contains security risks (from the readme).

Answer (score 2):

A Leaflet map has a [documented `scrollWheelZoom` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-scrollwheelzoom) that allows you to disable scrollwheel interactions (but still allows other ways to zoom the map, such as the zoom buttons).

In plain Javascript, this is used like `var map = L.map({ scrollWheelZoom: false })`. I'm not well versed in R, but you should try `leaflet(options = leafletOptions(scrollWheelZoom = false))` or variations thereof.

Answer (score 1):

I think your zoom options might need to go in the providerTiles function. I.e. `addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options = providerTileOptions(minZoom=12, maxZoom=12))`

Comment: It works for me. It works better with a smaller zoom number (like 2 or 3). I can't recreate your example entirely because I don't have your dataset but this is the code I'm using - `leaflet() %>% 
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron", options = providerTileOptions(minZoom = 3, maxZoom = 3))`

Comment: I presume the reason it does not work on mine because I have combined multiple tiles in a single map. Strangely, I added the script you shared with me in every addProviderTiles, and still does not work. I will fiddle with it a bit more :)